# If you want to wake up at 7 tomorrow

Tags: conditional-constructions

I have searched a lot on the Internet and it seems this sentence isn't a correct sentence.
Even I've searched for sentences like:

> - If you want to get up at 7 tomorrow
> - If you want to wake up early tomorrow

and some other variations without any success. Would someone please explain to me what is wrong with this sentence and how I can correct it?

P.S: This is the situation. One of my friends has an interview tomorrow morning and I want to advise him to get up at 7.

P.S 2: I know that there should be a main-clause after the if-clause. Something like: `if you want to get up at 7 tomorrow, you should go to bed at 10 today.`

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to say? What you have so far is just half of a thought.  It is not a full sentence.

Comment: Just so you know, it's a clause, not a sentence. To form a complete sentence, you'd need to add more (for example, _"If you want to wake up early tomorrow, be sure to set your alarm"_, or, _"[Jonas](http://itiswhatitis.weei.com/sports/newengland/football/patriots/2014/11/21/reports-jonas-gray-missed-practice-after-oversleeping/), if you want to get up at 7 tomorrow, make sure your phone is fully charged"_). But there's nothing wrong with how your clause is worded.

Comment: @J.R. & Catija: I know it should be followed by a main clause. I just didn't right it there because my focus was on the first part. I should've written to clarify the sentences. I've just updated my question.

Comment: Yep, what you've got is perfectly fine!  Nothing to fix about it.

Comment: @Catija I think this sentence should be part of parents-kids daily dialog, so why I can't even find one occurrence of such a sentence on the Internet?

Comment: @J.R.: The problem is that I can't find any occurrence of the first part of the sentences that you mentioned on the Internet. Maybe I am putting too much trust on the Internet to improve my English skills.

Comment: Masoud - Maybe :-) At least now you know that "can't find on Google" ≠ "must be ungrammatical for some reason".

Comment: Do you use quote marks when you search? If you're looking for exact phrase matches, **always** put them in quotes: "if you want to get up". This search has over 14.5 million hits https://www.google.com/search?q=If+you+want+to+wake+up&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22If+you+want+to+wake+up%22

Comment: @Catija - Interesting. The number of hits goes down to less than 30, though, when you change the search from "if you want to wake up" to "if you want to wake up [at 7](https://www.google.com/search?q=If+you+want+to+wake+up&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22If+you+want+to+wake+up+at+7%22&safe=off&start=20)". (Leaving off the '7' puts you [back in the thousands](https://www.google.com/search?q=If+you+want+to+wake+up&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22If+you+want+to+wake+up+at%22&safe=off&start=100), though.)

Comment: Why would you care about **at 7** specifically? It's not going to be any more or less grammatical than **at 5** or **at 10** or, more generally, **early**? There's no reason to include that in your phrase search. The word after **up** can be any of many different options.

Comment: @Catija - Of course! I'm just guessing at why the O.P. might have had problems finding examples.

Comment: @J.R. Sorry!  For some reason I didn't look at the person who posted the comment and had assumed it was the OP.

Comment: @Catija I tried to find "If you want to wake up at 7 tomorrow" at first, then I used get up instead of wake up and continued to substitute every word in that sentence with all possible synonyms and substitutions. Overall, I found less than 50 results so I though I am using a grammatically wrong sentence. Or at least a very unnatural clause. Some part of the problem was me not having enough confidence as a non-native English speaker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find something that you wrote on the internet, that could mean one of two things:

1. You have written something so poorly and ungrammatical that it needs to be fixed.
2. You have written something so original that you can't find your particular wording on the internet.

Not every valid sentence exists in cyberspace. This is a case where you've written something that's both grammatical and natural-sounding, yet, for some reason, people haven't blogged much about waking up at 7 o'clock – at least, not by using the same words you are using.

By the way, inserting an asterisk as a wildcard in your Google search can help. For example, when I tried searching for:

> `"if you want to get up at * tomorrow"`

I found a few wordings. One was in an [English exercise](http://speakspeak.com/english-grammar-exercises/intermediate/apostrophe-d-meaning-had-or-would):

> You'd better go to bed early tonight **if you want to get up at 5 o'clock tomorrow**.

The other was in a [plan for a mountain hike](http://students.washington.edu/climb/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=1832):

> We're meeting at 5:00am at the museum. So **if you want to get up at 4:40 tomorrow morning** then respond fast!

So, if you can't find a phrase like "If you want to get up at 7 tomorrow" on the internet, perhaps the **time** is the only thing wrong with your search.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. So that sentence isn't grammatically incorrect and it doesn't sound strange to a native speaker. And thanks for teaching me how to use * in google searches. I thought such a sentence should be a part of daily parents-children conversations so I was sure something is wrong with my sentence.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the phrase "wake up at 7 tomorrow" or "if you want to wake up at 7 tomorrow, [then ...]". It sounds completely normal to me (native speaker of British English).

Comment: Thank you for your help. So it doesn't sound strange to you. Is it?

Comment: @Masoud - The only change I would make in your PS2 sentence would be changing _today_ to _tonight_: _If you want to get up at 7 tomorrow, you should go to bed at 10 **tonight**._ (Your version is not ungrammatical, but I think _tonight_ would fit better.)

Comment: @J.R. Did you mean to make that a comment to the question, rather than a comment to my answer?